# Why console.log can not output properties of objects are created by vary ways?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I will be very obliged if u help me to realize why properties that can be shown by method getOwnPropertyDescriptor cannot be outputted by usual console.log. And waiting for your explanations why node 18.0 gets crazy about Object.create() and I cannot output the properties in anyway ^_^

```js
//Usual option
console.log('[MyObject1]')
const MyObject = {text: null};
console.log("MyObject: ", MyObject); // all right

console.log('[MyObject2]')
const MyObject2 = {};
Object.defineProperty(MyObject2, 'text' , {value: null});
console.log(MyObject2) // why nothing ?
console.log(MyObject2.text) // it is
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyObject2, 'text')); // And descriptor is too

console.log('[MyObject3]')
const MyObject3 = Object.create({text: null});
console.log(MyObject3) // it can be or not it depeneds on node compiler...
console.log(MyObject3.text) // Again it is
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyObject3, 'text')); // Why undefined ?
// P. S.
// I have no ideas why no output by console.log() and no descriptor in VS Code
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: `text` is not an own property of MyObject3. It comes from the prototype.

Comment: also, when using `Object.defineProperty`, [the default for `enumerable` is `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, properties added on the objects using `Object.defineProperty` method are not enumerable. You have to explicitly set the property to be enumerable.

```js
const MyObject2 = {};
Object.defineProperty(MyObject2, 'text', {
  value: null,
  enumerable: true
});
console.log(MyObject2);
```

In the last code example, `text` is defined in the prototype object of the `MyObject3` and as `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` returns own properties, not the inherited ones, `text` is not returned by this method.

```js
const MyObject3 = Object.create({text: null});
const MyObject3Proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(MyObject3);

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(MyObject3Proto, 'text'));
```